# Sqlite returns null value

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I am trying to get the phone number in BroadCastReceiver from database but it's  giving me empty value. Database has 50 entries. I am trying to do something like 
 **SELECT PHONE_NUMBER FROM TABLE WHERE ID=?** and returning to result in phone.

```
public String getPhone(String req){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLite=appalaHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String phone=null;
    String[] columns={appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER};
    String selection=appalaHelper.UID+"=? ";
    String[] selectionArgs={req};
    Cursor cursor=sqLite.query(AppalaHelper.TABLE,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        phone=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER));
    }
    return phone;
```

}

BroadCastReceiver

```
 appleHelperAdapter=new AppalaHelperAdapter(context);
    String requestCode=intent.getExtras().getString("de");
    meeSender=appleHelperAdapter.getPhone(requestCode);
 // Here I am getting null value instead of phone number
    Toast.makeText(context, meeSender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    appleHelperAdapter.Delete(requestCode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
```

The `moveToFirst()` moves to the first returned row.
The `moveToNext()` then tries to move to the second returned row, which does not exist.

It is common to use a `do`/`while` loop so that the `moveToNext()` call happens *after* the loop body, but the cursor is initially positioned before the first row, so you can simply use:

```java
Cursor cursor = sqLite.query(...);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER));
}
```

But when you want to read only a single value, better use a simpler [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

```java
public String getPhone(String req) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = appalaHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(db,
                "SELECT "+appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER+
                " FROM "+AppalaHelper.TABLE+
                " WHERE "+appalaHelper.UID+" = ?",
                new String[]{ req });
}
```

Comment: Yeah!!  Cool thanks bro.. I removed cursor.moveToFirst()  and it worked like a charm  ;) Can you please tell me where can I find good  documentation on sqlite database for android? Your codes are powerful!!

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `moveToFirst()` and BEFORE checking phone value `moveToNext()` (in while loop), your code skips the first record.  In case your SELECT returns only one line, your result will seem NULL.

Consider using `cursor.getCount()` in these circumstances.

I would further like to point out that if you plan on looping through cursor, you should attribute values to an array instead of what you are doing.  All depends on whether or not your code deals with multiple phone numbers as an answer (beyond this post's scope).

```
public String[] getPhone(String req){
  SQLiteDatabase sqLite=appalaHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  String[] phone;
  String[] columns={appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER};
  String selection=appalaHelper.UID+"=? ";
  String[] selectionArgs={req};
  Cursor cursor=sqLite.query(AppalaHelper.TABLE,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
  int counter = 0;
  while (cursor.moveToNext()){
      phone[counter]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER));
  }
  return phone[];
}
```

OR

```
public String getPhone(String req){
  SQLiteDatabase sqLite=appalaHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  String phone = null;
  String[] columns={appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER};
  String selection=appalaHelper.UID+"=? ";
  String[] selectionArgs={req};
  Cursor cursor=sqLite.query(AppalaHelper.TABLE,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
  If (cursor.getCount()>0){
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      phone=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER));
  }
  return phone;
}
```

Comment: Thanks tony, I already got the answer from  CL , he made me clear on cursor.moveToFirst() and cursor.moveToNext() . And you made me clear on how  it  works and gave me an example of using cursor.moveToFirst() in this situation using cursor.getCount()>0 thanks a ton for your answers!! I have only 1 reputation otherwise, I will vote your answer up!  :)